# Zeppelin exception with Spark Basic Features

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I teach a class on Scala and Spark. I've been demonstrating Zeppelin for five years now (and using it for a bit longer than that).

For the last couple of years, whenever I demonstrate Zeppelin, using the distribution out-of-the-box, I can only show the Spark Basic Features Notebook. When I do this, all of the paragraphs come up as they should. If I try to change the age in the age field, or simply try to re-run any of the paragraphs, I get an exception.

I repeat: this is out-of-the-box. I downloaded the 0.9.0-preview2 version, started the daemon, and opened the provided notebook. Any ideas? I'm on a MacBook Pro with OS 10.15.7. I also have Spark spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7 installed.

Here's the error that I get:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkSqlInterpreter.internalInterpret(SparkSqlInterpreter.java:105)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.AbstractInterpreter.interpret(AbstractInterpreter.java:47)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:110)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:776)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:668)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:172)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.AbstractScheduler.runJob(AbstractScheduler.java:130)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.ParallelScheduler.lambda$runJobInScheduler$0(ParallelScheduler.java:39)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: bank; line 2 pos 5;
'Sort ['age ASC NULLS FIRST], true
+- 'Aggregate ['age], ['age, count(1) AS value#4L]
   +- 'Filter ('age < 30)
      +- 'UnresolvedRelation [bank]

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1(CheckAnalysis.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$adapted(CheckAnalysis.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:177)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$foreachUp$1(TreeNode.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$foreachUp$1$adapted(TreeNode.scala:176)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$foreachUp$1(TreeNode.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$foreachUp$1$adapted(TreeNode.scala:176)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$foreachUp$1(TreeNode.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$foreachUp$1$adapted(TreeNode.scala:176)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.checkAnalysis$(CheckAnalysis.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1(Analyzer.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$analyzed$1(QueryExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$2(Dataset.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$1(SparkSession.scala:607)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:602)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:650)
    ... 15 more
```